# How can I find out if my light bulb is a full spectrum?

Tags: lighting

I'm suffering from winter depression, so I would like to have a full spectrum bulb at my desk. My desk lamp has an intense white light. So, I was wondering if it was a full spectrum light already. How can I find out?

Oh, I'm in Germany, if that is helpful.

Comment: Are there any markings on the bulb? If so, try entering them into your favorite search engine to see if you can find specifications.

Comment: Typical specs for SAD are 5000k color temp, 90 cri and 10000 lux intensity with the intensity being the most important part. It's not the color so much as simulating the brightness.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I can't see the markings on the bulb because they're in the lamp. I don't want to open it since it's not mine. Therefore, I was hoping for some other indicator. The light is very bright though. @mac too